# Replace Underscores characters with Space inside a String value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This is a rather simple question.

I have a date variables formated like: `25_December_2010`

I would like a statement or a bit of code in the `VBA macro` that will transform that string value from: `25_December_2010` to `25 December 2010`.

Somehow be able to remove the `underscores` from inside the `String` value....

Comment: `strDate=Replace(strDate,"_"," ")`?

Comment: This is correct! It works. Sorry for the ultra basicness of question buy i am getting chewed up in work having little time to look it up. If you want you can put it on plain sight in an answer that i will mark as correct for other users as well. Again thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, use code below:

```
Dim strDate As String
strDate = "25_December_2010"
strDate = Replace(strDate,"_"," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar in a macro I'm using for data cleaning so I took @simoco's answer and created a simple but mostly safe macro/sub.

```
Sub ConvertSpaceToUnderscore()
    Dim strCellValue As String

    ' Use basic error handling if more than 1 cell is selected, or
    ' possibly if something that isn't a cell is selected.
    On Error GoTo SelectionTooBig
        strCellValue = Selection.Value
        strCellValue = Replace(strCellValue, " ", "_")
        Selection.Value = strCellValue
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Exit the sub if things went well
    Exit Sub
SelectionTooBig:
    MsgBox "Please select one cell at a time.", vbCritical, "Selection too large"
End Sub
```